# Tomcat: is NIO used although not being configured?

Tags: tomcat

According to the following article : http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-tomcat-nio , the way to know if a Tomcat instance uses NIO(and not BIO) is to look for:

```
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

On my Tomcat server I have:

```
grep "Initializing ProtocolHandler" /opt/tomcat/logs/*
/opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.2015-02-23.log:23-Feb-2015 15:20:00.627 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
/opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.2015-02-23.log:23-Feb-2015 15:20:00.665 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

However my server.xml does not contain anything that tells it to use NIO, my connector looks as follows:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

In other terms i didn't set the protocol to use org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol as in the above article.

How is it that still the server seems to be using NIO?

-- Additional information

- Tomcat version : 8.0.15.0
- JVM Version : 1.8.0_25-b17
- Spring MVC is being used.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However my server.xml does contain anything that tells it to use NIO,

NIO is the default HTTP and AJP connector implementation for the Tomcat 8.

> The default HTTP and AJP connector implementation has switched from
>   the Java blocking IO implementation (BIO) to the Java non-blocking IO
>   implementation (NIO). BIO may still be used but Servlet 3.1 and
>   WebSocket 1.0 features that use non-blocking IO will then use blocking
>   IO instead which may cause unexpected application behavior.

http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#Default_connector_implementation

Comment: Thx. How is it? Does it just ignore the protocol attribute set in server.xml? How would one switch to BIO then? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: The protocol attribute just defines Http or AJP not the class that implements NIO or BIO

Comment: But according to http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html it says clearly that a class can be set. It also says that if not set it would be using BIO or the APR if LD_LIBRARY_PATH is used. Since in my case i do not set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, i would assume it would use BIO, what tells Tomcat to use NIO?

Comment: APR -as-not-required-to-run-tomcat is one way to use NIO connector, still Tomcat8 uses NIO by default without requiring APR installation.

Comment: Sorry to insist, but do you have a pointer to documentation or Source code that proves that it uses NIO, since what you say currently contradicts the documentation linked above. Thx

Comment: The way the documentation is arranged and written tends to bring some confusion between APR and NIO. APR is a Apache library in which NIO is part of it, APR aims to optimize Tomcat performance on production environment. In the table of the bottom of the page check **classname** row to see that are two different classes for APR and NIO.

Comment: That's correct but it doesn't say that NIO is the default implementation. And the protocol row says that the default is actually BIO, which is the reason i was asking.